# Video size and border radius using a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, css, video-player

**How can I remove the `style` attribute from the `<video>` tag?**

I embedded a video on the front page using the video shortcode and applied a `border-radius` to it with CSS. It looks good.

I modified the video shortcode a bit in `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode', function( $output ) {

    $output = str_replace( "<video", "<video muted playsinline autoplay loop", $output );
    return $output;

});
```

The CSS:

```css
#video-246-1_html5{
pointer-events: none !important;
border-radius: 20px !important;
background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

**The problem:**

On mobile I want the video width to be 200px. When I shrink the video to 200px with CSS, it loses the border-radius and the edges become sharp again.

I've tried everything that I've thought of. I also noticed the `<video>` tag has a

```
style="width= X; height: X;"
```

-attribute, and that correlates with the `border-radius`.

So basically, **how can I remove the `style` attribute from the `<video>` tag?** (or shrink the video some other way for mobile devices while maintaining 20px border radius)

Link to page: [Webite](https://wordpress-384045-1206737.cloudwaysapps.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that happend because when you reduce the width of the video the height still the same as before and the border radius does't affect. See the following image:

[image: Look what happen here]

Do you see in the image how the radius of the edge looks a little cut when I leave the video with a higher height?

I think one solution could be, besides change the width to 200px, also change the height to same or similar as you can see in the following image.

[image]

Try it and let me know if this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks Adriana! Modifying the height did the trick!

Comment: @AlexBotham I am glad that this helped you. If this was the solution for you, you can mark this answer as Accepted in the left side ;-)